# Load achievements from Google Play without any Unity plugins only native code

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

It is possible to use this code from Unity samples:

```
//C#
Social.LoadAchievements (achievements => {
        if (achievements.Length > 0) {
            Debug.Log ("Got " + achievements.Length + " achievement instances");
            string myAchievements = "My achievements:\n";
            foreach (IAchievement achievement in achievements)
            {
                myAchievements += "\t" + 
                    achievement.id + " " +
                    achievement.percentCompleted + " " +
                    achievement.completed + " " +
                    achievement.lastReportedDate + "\n";
            }
            Debug.Log (myAchievements);
        }
        else
            Debug.Log ("No achievements returned");
    });
```

and get Google Play achievements. Or it's works only for iOs devices and for Android I have to use some plugins?

[This script](https://gist.github.com/StatelessPath/9561908) as I understood works only for iOs devise not for Android.

Why don't use standard Unity Google plugin?
- Because they don't teach it to load achievements.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Not implemented yet. Calls the callback with an empty list.
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadAchievements(Action<IAchievement[]> callback) {
        Logger.w("PlayGamesPlatform.LoadAchievements is not implemented.");
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.Invoke(new IAchievement[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the official Google Play Services plugin for Unity?

Here's a [Link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/integration/) to an official Google Developer web site, where you can find all the information you need to set it up correctly.

This plugin works on both Android and iOS Devices!

Comment: Because they don't teach it to load achievements. I did edit my question.